# How to get levels of a column based on a condition regarding another column

Tags: r, dataframe

If there is a data frame that looks like:

```
datas$A <- c("M","M","F","M","F","U","U")
datas$B <- c("cat","dog","cat","dog","cat","dog","dog")
```

I would like to do something along the lines of:

```
list_levels <- levels(datas$A where datas$B == "cat")
```

as output:

```
list_levels
"M" "F"
```

how would I proceed in doing this?

Comment: You could also use `list_levels <- unique(df$A[df$B == "cat"])`

Comment: `print(list_levels)` gives `[1] "M" "F"`. If this isn't what you need, I'm not sure what it is you are looking for

Comment: @KenS. Perfect. Is it possible to output the levels in quotation marks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list_levels <- unique(df$A[df$B == "cat"])
print(list_levels)
# [1] "M" "F"
```

Note that when you use `unique()`, it will return the unique values in the order they appear in `df$A` and *not* in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would do? :

```
levels(data[data$B == "cat", ]$A)
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
df <- data.frame(
  A = c("M","M","F","M","F"), 
  B = c("cat","dog","cat","dog","cat")
)

levels(df$A[df$B == "cat"])
#> [1] "F" "M"
```